# Use tableView willDisplay cell forRowAt indexPath for custom Cells (with custom height)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project I have a UITableView displaying custom cells of a fixed height.

When I segue to the ViewController, I want to run an animation in the tableViewCells. when i scroll down, and then back to the first cell I do not want to run the animation again.
To achieve this I am using `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. I then use an array to remember which cells have been on the screen already.

My function looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      let myCell = cell as! myTableViewCell
        if !alreadyShown.contains(indexPath) {
            alreadyShown.append(indexPath)
            myCell.animate()
        } else {
            myCell.dontAnimate()
        }
}
```

However, this seems to ignore the height of my cell. Therefore it runs for every indexPath that would have been displayed for standard cells (e.g. 17 times on an iPhone X), even though 14 of those 17 cells are not visible.
When i scroll down later, the animation is already finished for those 14 next cells.

Is there any way of telling the willDisplay cell function the cell height so that it knows which cells are actually going to be displayed? Or is there any other way of keeping score of which cells have actually been displayed already?

Comment: There is visbileCells property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells

Comment: Using that property (in scrollviewdidscroll) produces the same problem. I don’t know where else I would use it so that the animations would start automatically upon loading the viewcontroller, but only for the actually visible cells.

Comment: Why don't you run your animation at viewDidAppear()? just loop over visible cells

Comment: That’s a good idea! I will do some testing and get back with my results. thank you!

Comment: unfortunately, that solution does not work. There main problem with it is that there is no easy way of handling which cells already had an animation and which didn't without checking for visible cells in scrollviewdidscroll which would mean a major performance hit. Fortunately I found the solution which (marked as correct answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was setting the `estimatedRowHeight` for the tableView to a number equal to or greater than the actual hight of the cells in `viewDidLoad`. This made sure that `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is only called on the actually visible cells.